# Can you move a branch so that it is under another parent?

Tags: tortoisegit

I have a master repository.

Yesterday I started my first branch and called it **ImportPTS**.

But then I found this tutorial:

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

I would like to adopt it. Thus, I need to make a new branch from **master** called **develop**.

Then, ImportPTS needs to be under *that* branch instead. Eventually I will have other branches under *develop* until I am ready to merge it as a feature branch.

But is it possible? Can I move the branch as described?

### Clarification

Change from:

```
master
    ImportPTS
```

To

```
master
    develop
        ImportPTS
```

Comment: Try to rebase your feature-branch onto the `develop` branch. Don't be afraid of merge-conflicts, if any. After resolving merge-conflicts continue rebasing with `git rebase --continue`, abort with `git rebase --abort` or use your GUI client's commands.

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve, however, it sounds like a "rebase" task (https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-rebase.html).

Comment: @MrTux I have updated the question to make it clear. I have not used "rebase" before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do sounds like a "rebase" task - rewriting history of commits and, thus, has be used with caution.

In order to put the `ImportPTS` branch on top of `develop`, open the log dialog and switch to the `ImportPTS` branch. Then open the context menu on the latest commit of the `develop` branch and select "Rebase onto..." there.

Now a new dialog opens, where you can see all commits you want to "rebase" or put onto your `develop` branch. If you don't want to re-order, combine, skip or modify commits, just leave them as they are and click on "Start".

After that, your `ImportPTS` branch should be on top of the `develop` branch.

Also see https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-rebase.html.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.

Comment: I can see I misread the original tutorial. Develop is supposed to be parallel to master and not under it.

Comment: It doesn't matter what branch is on top of which other branch. The general progress is called rebasing.